# How to use sweetalert in apache cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova, sweetalert

I am working in a cordova application. I want to know how to include sweetalert in cordova.

**Note:** I don't use any framework like angular, react, framework7. I use Javascript and Ajax in my cordova application

Comment: just include it in your webpage like any other script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your HTML header (or download file localy and insert it the same way)

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

And use swal() function to display alert